# Laravel validation min array with specified value

Tags: php, laravel-8

I need to write validation for min array elements but with specified value.

I get from request field `photos` which contains array of arrays. Looking like that:

```
'photos' => [
    ['name' => 'example_name', 'type' => 'type_1'],
    ['name' => 'example_name2', 'type' => 'type_2'],
    ['name' => 'example_name3', 'type' => 'type_2'],
]
```

and i need to check that photos contains at least 3 elements where `type` = `type_1`

I know that exists `min` rule but how to check with specified key value?

Now I do it with prepareValidation and delete all other elements but it's looks terrbile